# Referencing non-static variables

Tags: boolean, components, unity-game-engine

I'm making a basic basket ball game and i have a public boolean called dunkComplete which activated after the ball is dunked and is attaced to the ball script, i am trying to reference this boolean in a game manager script but for some reason even though dunkComplete becomes true its game manager counterpart doesn't, heres the game manager script for reference.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class game_manager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Basket;

    private float x_value;
    private float y_value;

    public GameObject ball;
    private ball_script basketBallScript;
    private bool dunkCompleteOperation;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        basketBallScript = ball.GetComponent<ball_script>();

        Vector2 randomVector = new Vector2(Random.Range(-9f, 9f), Random.Range(0f, 3f));

        Debug.Log(randomVector);

        Instantiate(Basket, randomVector, transform.rotation);

        Instantiate(ball, new Vector2(0, -3.5f), transform.rotation);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        dunkCompleteOperation = basketBallScript.dunkComplete;

        if (dunkCompleteOperation == true)
        {
            Vector2 randomVector = new Vector2(Random.Range(-9f, 9f), Random.Range(0f, 3f));

            Instantiate(Basket, randomVector, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated thanks.

Comment: Can you share your ball_script? Also, is there only one ball or you spawn another after dunk or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your basketBallScript does not refer to the ball_script that the ball object that you instantiate. You should keep the reference to the GameObject that you created and then assign the basketBallScript.

Try this:

```
public class game_manager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Basket;

    private float x_value;
    private float y_value;

    public GameObject ball;
    private ball_script basketBallScript;
    private bool dunkCompleteOperation;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        Vector2 randomVector = new Vector2(Random.Range(-9f, 9f), Random.Range(0f, 3f));

        Debug.Log(randomVector);

        Instantiate(Basket, randomVector, transform.rotation);
        // Get the ref. to ballObj, which is instantiated. Then assign the script.
        GameObject ballObj = Instantiate(ball, new Vector2(0, -3.5f), 
        transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        basketBallScript = ballObj.GetComponent<ball_script>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        dunkCompleteOperation = basketBallScript.dunkComplete;

        if (dunkCompleteOperation == true)
        {
            Vector2 randomVector = new Vector2(Random.Range(-9f, 9f), Random.Range(0f, 3f));

            Instantiate(Basket, randomVector, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, just for making your code easier to follow to the others in the future, you might want to check out the [general naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions).